# Passing class as an argument to method and then using it to create new class item

Tags: c#, class, parameter-passing, void

So I am trying to make universal combat code and to do this i need to pass enemy class to my combat void. Now it looks like this:

```
static void Combat()
{
Character.Player player = new Character.Player();
Character.Gnome gnome = new Character.Gnome();
}
```

Class with characters looks like this:

```
class Character
{
//hp, damage and other universal stuff
}

class Player : Character
{
//hp, damage and stuff
}

class Enemy : Character
{
}

class Gnome : Enemy
{
//stuff
}

class Skeleton : Enemy
{
//stuff
}
```

So, for now, void Combat() isn't universal code because you can only fight gnome. I want to be able to do Combat(Skeleton) or Combat(Gnome) to fight this specific opponent. I've tried doing it like this

```
void Combat(Character.Enemy enemyType)
{
Character.enemyType enemy = new Character.enemyType();
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How does the `Combat` method use the `Character.Gnome` object or any other character?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) with a new [constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) like so:

```
void Combat<tEnemy>() where tEnemy : Character.Enemy, new()
{
    Character.Player player = new Character.Player();
    Character.Enemy enemy = new tEnemy();
}
```

The Combat function can be called like so:

```
Combat<Character.Gnome>();
Combat<Character.Skeleton>();
```

Another option is to accept the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) as a parameter in the combat function and use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) like so:

```
static void Combat(Type enemyType)
{
    Character.Player player = new Character.Player();
    Character.Enemy enemy = Activator.CreateInstance(enemyType) as Character.Enemy;
}
```

This function can be called using the [typeof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator like so:

```
Combat(typeof(Character.Gnome));
Combat(typeof(Character.Skeleton));
```

Using generics will give you compile time checking but is less flexible.
Passing in the type as a parameter is more flexible but will not give you compile time checking.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not only you helped me to solve my problem but also thanks to this example I finally understand generics and where keyword. Really man, you're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activator` class as follow
`Activator.CreateInstance(enemyType.GetType())`
It uses default constructor of type